# Opening Facebook app from safari using Facebook JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook signup flow where users can signup through Facebook. I use the facebook javascript SDK. Everything is working however I'm trying to find out if it's possible to open the Facebook app for the permissions instead of new safari window (where a lot of users will not be logged in).

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no connection between the browser and the app that the necessary data could be passed through.

Comment: If it was possible the SDK would do it automatically